# APC not working after centos and php upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, apc

I had centos 6.5 on my server. I upgraded to centos 7.

With this upgrade I have php 5.4 instead of php 5.3.

All works fine except APC and xhprof extension.

Here is the error I am having when I try to restart apache or any ather action conserning the web server.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xhprof: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2014 12:59:36)
```

Anyone to help , please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed apc via pecl. If yes, you will have to reinstall APC and xhprof via pecl to get them recompiled for your current PHP version

```
pecl install apc
pecl install xhprof
```

Comment: pecl/apc is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.13

Comment: Should I uninstall ?